# How to read the lines between two specific words in a text file (*.txt)?

Tags: c++

> 1.Container ID.txt
>
> Container Type: Refrigerated_Explosive    //Enter one serial no. per line
>
> 1990
>
> 1991
>
> 1992
>
> END RE

This is my input file for a c++ program.
My objective here is to read all the lines between the lines containing 'Refrigerated_Explosive' and 'RE' (i.e. I want to read the numbers 1990, 1991, 1992 in this case)

So far I've tried to store the second word in each line to a string variable using 'while(file1>>value>>type)' and compare it with 'Refrigerated_Explosive', if both are equal move to next line and read the content (and store in a different file) until second word is 'RE'.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file1;
    ofstream file2;
    int value;
    string type;
    file1.open("1.Container ID.txt"); //Input File
    if(file1)
    {
        file2.open("1.CID.txt"); //Output File
        while(file1>>value>>type)
        {
            if(type == "Refrigerated_Explosive") //If equal read from next line
            {
                while(file1>>value>>type)
                {
                    if(type != "RE") //Read until 'RE' not found
                        file2<<value<<endl;                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    cout<<"Source File not Found1!!!\n";
    file1.close();
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getline()` function to read a line, `getline()` stops reading if it meet new line character `\n`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream file1;
    ofstream file2;


    file1.open("input.txt"); //Input File
    file2.open("output.txt"); //output file

    string line;
    while(getline(file1,line))
    {
        //if the line contains "Refrigerated_Explosive" then read number until meet RE
        if(contains(line,"Refrigerated_Explosive"))
        {
            string number;
            while(getline(file1,number))  //read number and write to file output 
            {
                if(number!="RE")
                {
                    file2<<number<<"\n";
                }
                else return 0; //break if meet "RE"
            }
        }
    }

    file1.close();
    file2.close();
    return 0;
}
```